# Prove, that if the commutative ring has no zero divisors, then it is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative **finite** ring in which $ab = 0$ implies either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ for any $a,b \in R$. Then, $R$ is a field.

I do not understand how I should act. I tried different ways, but I was not able to prove this assertion.

Comment: You need additional conditions on $R$, a word was probably left out.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this is downvoted?

Comment: @k.stm: My best guess is that someone thought this looked like the OP was outsourcing his mathematical work.

Comment: @someoneyouknow, I made a mistake. Z is not a finite ring.

Comment: For further variations see [answers here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62548/242) This is one of the most frequently asked questions.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to prove is that a commutative ring with no zero divisors is a field. This is false unless $R$ is finite. If $R$ is finite, the only thing you have to show is that every non-zero element of $R$ has an inverse. Then the solution is for example here: [How to show that a finite commutative ring without zero divisors is a field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314936/how-to-show-that-a-finite-commutative-ring-without-zero-divisors-is-a-field)